# Passing values from another class Incompatible types

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple array that I declare below but getting incompatible types error, when trying to pass values from another class.  Also, is there a better way of declaring the array below instead of saying initialize to 10 positions?

```
    float[] myarray = new float[10];

    for(StudentClass score:total){

       myarray  = ((float)score.getRiskValue()); //incompatible types here
    }
```

Comment: a float is different from an array of floats.

Comment: You are trying to set an array to a float, you should do something like myArray[index] = ((float)...) (this will require you to use a "simple" for loop, aka, int i = 0; i < total.length; i++)

Comment: myarray  is an Array; ((float)score.getRiskValue());  is a single float value

Comment: Use it like this myarray[0]  = ((float)score.getRiskValue());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of foreach use for loop

```
ArrayList<StudentClass> score = new ArrayList<>();//initialize the list with data here
float[] myarray = new float[score.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<score.size();i++){    
       myarray[i]  = ((float)score.getRiskValue());
    }
```